# JavaFX application freeze when i append log4j to textarea

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-2

I have managed to append my log4j messages to a javafx textarea component, however if a background application task runs, the GUI is freezing.

So something in the implementation is missing or mis-configured.

Here is my custom log4j appender:

```
public class TextAreaAppender extends WriterAppender {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TextAreaAppender.class.getName());

    private static volatile TextArea textArea = null;

    public static void setTextArea(final TextArea textArea) {
        TextAreaAppender.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void append(final LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {

        final String message = this.layout.format(loggingEvent);

        try {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                try {
                    if (textArea != null) {
                        if (textArea.getText().length() == 0) {
                            textArea.setText(message);
                        } else {
                            textArea.selectEnd();
                            textArea.insertText(textArea.getText().length(),
                                message);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (final Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to append log to text area: "
                        + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (final IllegalStateException e) {
            // ignore case when the platform hasn't yet been iniitialized
        }
    }
```

and here is how i insert the textarea component into my fxml controller:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    ...
    @FXML
    private TextArea logText;
    ...
    @Override
    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ...
        logText.setEditable(false);
        TextAreaAppender.setTextArea(logText);
    }
```

Finally here is my log4j configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, textarea, stdout
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Append the logs to the GUI
log4j.appender.textarea = com.npap.fxutils.TextAreaAppender
log4j.appender.textarea.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.textarea.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.textarea.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

What could the reason of GUI freezing could be?

In the background application runs several tasks/processes and the action on which application is freezing is when the following class and its methods are called:

```
class StorageSCP extends StorageService  implements AssociationListener {
    ...
    private final DcmRcv dcmrcv;

     public StorageSCP(DcmRcv dcmrcv, String[] sopClasses) {
         super(sopClasses);
         this.dcmrcv = dcmrcv;
     }
     ...
    /** Overwrite {@link StorageService#cstore} to send delayed C-STORE RSP 
    * by separate Thread, so reading of following received C-STORE RQs from
    * the open association is not blocked.
    */
    @Override
    public void cstore(final Association as, final int pcid, DicomObject rq,
        PDVInputStream dataStream, String tsuid)
        throws DicomServiceException, IOException {

        final DicomObject rsp = CommandUtils.mkRSP(rq, CommandUtils.SUCCESS);
        onCStoreRQ(as, pcid, rq, dataStream, tsuid, rsp);

        if (dcmrcv.getDimseRspDelay() > 0) {
            dcmrcv.executor().execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(dcmrcv.getDimseRspDelay());
                        as.writeDimseRSP(pcid, rsp);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            as.writeDimseRSP(pcid, rsp);
        }

        onCStoreRSP(as, pcid, rq, dataStream, tsuid, rsp);
    }
     ...
     @Override
     protected void onCStoreRQ(Association association, int pcid, DicomObject dcmReqObj,
                                PDVInputStream dataStream, String transferSyntaxUID,
                                DicomObject dcmRspObj)
            throws DicomServiceException, IOException {
         final DicomOutputStream outStream = new DicomOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dicomFile), 600000));

        try {
            outStream.writeFileMetaInformation(fileMetaDcmObj);
            dataStream.copyTo(outStream);            
        } catch (DicomServiceException e) {
        } finally {
            outStream.close();  
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void associationAccepted(final AssociationAcceptEvent associationAcceptEvent) {
        final UUID assocUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
        final Association association = associationAcceptEvent.getAssociation();
        associationDataMap.put(association, assocUUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void associationClosed(final AssociationCloseEvent associationCloseEvent) {
        final Association association = associationCloseEvent.getAssociation();
        associationDataMap.remove(association);
        final Integer assocInstanceCnt = associationCounterMap.get(association);
    removeAssociationCounter(association);
    }

    private final Map<Association, UUID> associationDataMap = new HashMap<Association, UUID>();
    private final Map<Association, Integer> associationCounterMap = new HashMap<Association, Integer>();
```

This class and its methods are called in the background when a listener (listening for incoming dicom images association requests receives such).

I do not know if this code helps however application behavior is like the following:

1. Application starts fine, GUI is working fine (can switch tabs, edit
   fields etc.). I can also see its log in my log4j textarea
2. When i receive some incoming dicom images for parsing (association
   requests) then the entire application freezes.
3. In the background application is running normally, no exceptions are
   thrown and the tasks run without any problem
4. Even if all association requests concludes (accepted and processed)
   the GUI remains freezed.

I hope all that info above helps...

Comment: How often is `append()` called?

Comment: I used the code for log4j appender that is posted here: http://www.rshingleton.com/javafx-log4j-textarea-log-appender/. I assume that append() is called whenever a logging event is fired.

Comment: And how often are you firing a logging event?

Comment: The reason I am asking this question is because `Platform.runLater()` adds the Runnable to an event queue. So, if you flood JavaFX with too many pending Runnables, the application may become unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks @ItachiUchiha ... Indeed this make sense. Check my log4j configuration (added to the question). Since my log level is INFO, there are several logging events per second ... So this could hang Application's GUI i guess... Could you think of any alternatives?

Comment: TextArea may be an overkill for your usecase. Try to use a simpler control like Text or Label.

Comment: What if instead of updating the `TextArea` from the `LogAppender` you append your log line into a StringProperty``and bind that to the TextArea?

Comment: For the reasons described by ItachiUchiha, I would make the appender debounce the messages. E.g. store the log messages in memory (a `List<String>` or something). Then with a timer, set to a reasonable interval, flush all the stored messages to the UI. Setting a limit on the buffer of the UI could also help. Also consider the comment of Uluk Biy, using a simpler control.

Comment: OK thank u all... i will consider the advices/guideliness provided to your comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextArea is not suited for vast amounts of text because it is backed by one big text node. You are better of using one of the virtual controls eg a ListView if it is not editable or one of the StyledText controls available.

The most common used are:

- RichTextFX: https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/
- StyledTextArea: http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2015/07/24/developing-a-source-code-editor-in-javafx-without-e4-and-osgi/